# Spring data jpa - the best way to return object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have object like this:

```
@Entity
public class DocumentationRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String topic;
    private boolean isParent;
    @OneToMany
    private List<DocumentationRecord> children;
...
}
```

now I would like to get only topics and ids. Is there way to get it in format like this:

```
[
{
id: 4234234,
topic: "fsdfsdf"
},...
]
```

Because even using only this query

```
public interface DocumentationRecordRepository extends CrudRepository<DocumentationRecord, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT d.topic as topic, d.id as id FROM DocumentationRecord d")
    List<DocumentationRecord> getAllTopics();
}
```

I was only able to get record like this:

```
[
  [
    "youngChild topic",
    317
  ],
  [
    "oldChild topic",
    318
  ],
  [
    "child topic",
    319
  ],
]
```

I don't like array of arrays I would like to get array of object with property id and topic. What is the nicest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Spring Data JPA you can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

**Interface based**:

```
public interface IdAndTopic {
    Long getId();
    String getTopic();
}
```

**Class based** (DTO):

```
@Value // Lombok annotation
public class IdAndTopic {
   Long id;
   String topic;
}
```

Then create a simple query method in your repo:

```
public interface DocumentationRecordRepository extends CrudRepository<DocumentationRecord, Long> {

    List<IdAndTopic> findBy();
}
```

You can create even dynamic query method:

```
List<T> findBy(Class<T> type);
```

Then use it like this:

```
List<DocumentationRecord> records = findBy(DocumentationRecord.class);
List<IdAndTopic> idAndTopics = findBy(IdAndTopic.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class with attributes id and topic and use constructor injection into query. Sth like below

```
@Query("SELECT NEW your.package.SomeObject(d.id, d.topic) FROM DocumentationRecord d")
```